# 'value_from': no matching overloaded function found Project1

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-mp11

I am implementing a program，It can make a function call based on the given string.
The implementation is as follows:
it might be a bit long, here is the [online version](https://godbolt.org/z/4jMr6fv6E)

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<stack>
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::json;

// C1:class name
// C2:pointer to member function
// R:return type of member function
// A: member function parameter pack
// I: Parameter pack expansion
template<class C1, class C2, class R, class... A, std::size_t... I>
boost::json::value
call_impl_(C1& c1, R(C2::* pmf)(A...), boost::json::array const& args,
  std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  return boost::json::value_from((c1.*pmf)(boost::json::value_to< boost::remove_cv_ref_t<A> >(args[I])...));
}
// C1: class name
// C2: pointer to member function
// R : return type of member function
// A : member function parameter pack
// args: member function args
template<class C1, class C2, class R, class... A>
boost::json::value
call_impl(C1& c1, R(C2::* pmf)(A...), boost::json::array const& args)
{
  if (args.size() != sizeof...(A))
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number of arguments");
  return call_impl_(c1, pmf, args, std::index_sequence_for<A...>());
}
// c:class name
// method: member function name
// args: member function args
// 
template<class C>
boost::json::value call(C& c, boost::string_view method, boost::json::value const& args = boost::json::array{})
{
  using Fd = boost::describe::describe_members<C,
    boost::describe::mod_public | boost::describe::mod_function>;
  bool found = false;
  boost::json::value result;
  boost::mp11::mp_for_each<Fd>([&](auto D) {
    if (!found && method == D.name)
    {
      result = call_impl(c, D.pointer, args.as_array());
      found = true;
    }
    });
  if (!found)
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid method name");
  }
  return result;
}
//    BOOST_DESCRIBE_CLASS(Solution, (), (member_func1, member_func2, member_func3), (), ());

class StackOfPlates {
  vector<stack<int>> store;
  int capacity;
public:
  StackOfPlates(int cap) {
    capacity = cap;
  }
  void push(int val) {
    if (capacity == 0)return;
    if (store.empty() || store.back().size() == capacity)
      store.emplace_back(stack<int>());
    store.back().push(val);
  }
  int pop() {
    if (capacity == 0 || store.empty())
      return -1;
    int res = store.back().top();
    store.back().pop();
    if (store.back().empty())
      store.pop_back();
    return res;
  }
  int popAtStack(int index) {
    if (capacity == 0 || index >= store.size() || store[index].empty())return -1;
    int res = store[index].top();
    store[index].pop();
    if (store[index].empty()) {
      store.erase(store.begin() + index);
    }
    return res;
  }
  BOOST_DESCRIBE_CLASS(StackOfPlates, (), (push, pop, popAtStack), (), ())
};

int main()
{
  vector<std::string> t1{ "push", "push", "popAt", "pop", "pop" };
  vector<vector<int>> t2{ { 1},{2},{1},{},{} };
  StackOfPlates obj(1);// (init1, init2);
  for (int i = 0; i < t1.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::string sa = t1[i];
    std::vector<int> sb = t2[i];
    boost::json::value sc = boost::json::value_from(sb);
    std::cout << call(obj, sa, sc) << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The library that needs to be installed is `boost 1.80`
The`call_impl` relevant code comes from the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#example_json_rpc)
development environment is `windows11`/ `Visual Studio 2022 (v143)`
The error message is:

```bash
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672   'value_from': no matching overloaded function found Project1    C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp  26
```

output:

```cpp
>main.cpp
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(26,23): error C2672: 'value_from': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\json\value_from.hpp(125,1): message : could be 'void boost::json::value_from(T &&,boost::json::value &)'
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(26,23): message : 'void boost::json::value_from(T &&,boost::json::value &)': expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
1>C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\json\value_from.hpp(125): message : see declaration of 'boost::json::value_from'
1>C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\json\value_from.hpp(83,1): message : or       'boost::json::value boost::json::value_from(T &&,boost::json::storage_ptr)'
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(26,23): message : Failed to specialize function template 'boost::json::value boost::json::value_from(T &&,boost::json::storage_ptr)'
1>C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\json\value_from.hpp(83): message : see declaration of 'boost::json::value_from'
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(25,1): message : With the following template arguments:
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(25,1): message : 'T=R'
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(36): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::json::value call_impl_<C1,StackOfPlates,R,int,0>(C1 &,R (__cdecl StackOfPlates::* )(int),const boost::json::array &,std::integer_sequence<size_t,0>)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            C1=StackOfPlates,
1>            R=void
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(47): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::json::value call_impl<C,StackOfPlates,void,int>(C1 &,R (__cdecl StackOfPlates::* )(int),const boost::json::array &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            C=StackOfPlates,
1>            C1=StackOfPlates,
1>            R=void
1>        ]
1>C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\mp11\algorithm.hpp(1037): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void call::<lambda_1>::operator ()<boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_1>::()::_boost_desc,1>>(_T1) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _T1=boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_1>::()::_boost_desc,1>
1>        ]
1>C:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\mp11\algorithm.hpp(1054): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'F boost::mp11::detail::mp_for_each_impl<boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_1>::()::_boost_desc,1>,boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_2>::()::_boost_desc,1>,boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_3>::()::_boost_desc,1>,_Ty>(boost::mp11::mp_list<boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_1>::()::_boost_desc,1>,boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_2>::()::_boost_desc,1>,boost::describe::detail::member_descriptor<boost_public_member_descriptor_fn::<lambda_3>::()::_boost_desc,1>>,F &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            F=call::<lambda_1>,
1>            _Ty=call::<lambda_1>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(47): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'call::<lambda_1> boost::mp11::mp_for_each<Fd,call::<lambda_1>>(F &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            F=call::<lambda_1>
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\mingy\source\repos\Project1\Project1\main.cpp(116): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::json::value call<StackOfPlates>(C &,boost::string_view,const boost::json::value &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            C=StackOfPlates
1>        ]
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I was using boost1.78 it worked fine, today I reinstalled boost 1.80 and got this kind of error.
I'm not very familiar with mp11, so I can't understand it.
Can someone explain what the problem is and how can I fix it?

I once asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72392699/how-to-call-a-parameterless-function-using-boostjsonvalue) related to this

Comment: If you read the error message in the output, the second line tells you what you need to know. You are currently using the value_from function with only one argument, whereas it needs two.

Comment: Also please consider the readability of your code, at the moment it is very hard to decipher what you're trying to do due to the structure and the naming conventions

Comment: @alexheslop1 I don't think the error on the first line correctly reveals why the error occurred.
Also, you only need to focus on the `call` function, the other parts are just tests to perform function calls simulation

Comment: @alexheslop1 Agreed. I fixed the bulk in my answer. Note though that the real magic is just a [Boost Describe example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#example_json_rpc) (Kargath: you can't focus on anything in generic code like this unless you understand how it is used, so yeah "sq = t17[i]" etc. is exceptionally poor naming. And completely unnecessary, compare my answer code :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your code with GCC gives:

```
<source>:18:18: error: invalid use of void expression
   18 |         (c1.*pmf)(json::value_to<boost::remove_cv_ref_t<A>>(args[I])...));https://godbolt.org/z/E7h4M7bjE
```

It makes sense because you "reflect" the `push` member function which returns `void`. The simplest you can do is to make it return something:

```
bool push(int val) {
    if (capacity == 0)
        return false;
    if (store.empty() || store.back().size() == capacity)
        store.emplace_back();
    store.back().push(val);
    return true;
}
```

Now you have more luck with that Boost Describe sample code: https://godbolt.org/z/xbcT3jda1

### Fixing The Style

Apart from the non-existent `popAt` method name, fixing some fallout like:

- mixing signed/unsigned arithmetic
- using `.at(idx)` in favor of `.operator[](idx)` because I wouldn't vouch for your logic to be correct :)
- no `using namespace`
- moving the `#ifdef design` into `namespace RPC`
- parallel vectors: Just Don't Do It

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a50b64df35c0e417)**

```
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
#include <boost/mp11.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace json = boost::json;

namespace RPC {
    template <class C1, class C2, class R, class... A, std::size_t... I>
    json::value call_impl_( //
        C1& c1, R (C2::*pmf)(A...), json::array const& args,
        std::index_sequence<I...>) //
    {
        return json::value_from(
            (c1.*pmf)(json::value_to<boost::remove_cv_ref_t<A>>(args[I])...));
    }

    template <class C1, class C2, class R, class... A>
    json::value call_impl(                                   //
        C1& c1, R (C2::*pmf)(A...), json::array const& args) //
    {
        if (args.size() != sizeof...(A))
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number of arguments");
        return call_impl_(c1, pmf, args, std::index_sequence_for<A...>());
    }

    template <class C>
    json::value call(C& c, boost::string_view method,
                     json::value const& args = json::array{}) //
    {
        namespace bd = boost::describe;
        using Fd = bd::describe_members<C, bd::mod_public | bd::mod_function>;

        bool        found = false;
        json::value result;
        boost::mp11::mp_for_each<Fd>([&](auto D) {
            if (!found && method == D.name) {
                result = call_impl(c, D.pointer, args.as_array());
                found  = true;
            }
        });

        return found ? result
                     : throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid method name");
    }
} // namespace RPC

class StackOfPlates {
    using Stack = std::stack<int>;
    std::vector<Stack> store;
    size_t             capacity;

  public:
    StackOfPlates(size_t cap) { capacity = cap; }

    bool push(int val) {
        if (capacity == 0)
            return false;
        if (store.empty() || store.back().size() == capacity)
            store.emplace_back();
        store.back().push(val);
        return true;
    }

    int pop() {
        if (capacity == 0 || store.empty())
            return -1;
        int res = store.back().top();
        store.back().pop();
        if (store.back().empty())
            store.pop_back();
        return res;
    }

    int popAtStack(size_t index) {
        if (capacity == 0 || index >= store.size() || store.at(index).empty())
            return -1;
        int res = store.at(index).top();
        store.at(index).pop();
        if (store.at(index).empty()) {
            store.erase(store.begin() + index);
        }
        return res;
    }
    BOOST_DESCRIBE_CLASS(StackOfPlates, (), (push, pop, popAtStack), (), ())
};

int main() {
    struct {
        std::string method;
        json::array args;
    } actions[]{
        {"push", {1}}, {"push", {2}}, {"popAtStack", {1}},
        {"pop", {}},   {"pop", {}},
    };

    // std::vector init1{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}, init2{1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4};
    StackOfPlates obj(1); // (init1, init2);

    for (auto& [method, args] : actions)
        std::cout << "RPC Call: " << method << args << " -> "
                  << RPC::call(obj, method, args) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
RPC Call: push[1] -> true
RPC Call: push[2] -> true
RPC Call: popAtStack[1] -> 2
RPC Call: pop[] -> 1
RPC Call: pop[] -> -1
```

See also Compiler explorer [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/frfbnvb9j), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/s6vG5as3b) and [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/Td1jnKjrq)

### UPDATE

Alternatively you can make the `call_impl_` deal with `void` return types, of course:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<R, void>) {
    (c1.*pmf)(json::value_to<boost::remove_cv_ref_t<A>>(args[I])...);
    return json::value{};
} else {
    return json::value_from((c1.*pmf)(
        json::value_to<boost::remove_cv_ref_t<A>>(args[I])...));
}
```

See it live as well: [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/vE8fYfq7z), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Edf9sP58v) and [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/bsjd3Mb31)

Comment: Sorry, the code in the `StackOfPlates` part comes from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/dinner-plate-stacks/), my intention is to implement a code that can be used for [design](https://leetcode.com/ tag/design/)-like function mock calls, allowing me to convert string arguments into corresponding function calls.
So the return value of push cannot be modified.
Do you have a better way?

Comment: No. You just have to fix the problem that void cannot be converted to json. That's not better, just different: e.g [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/vE8fYfq7z), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Edf9sP58v) and [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/bsjd3Mb31)